# Animating sequence of images in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i have this code  to show animation of a image

```
-(void) blink:(ccTime) delta {


    animateblink ++; //adds 1 every frame

    if (animateblink <= 6 ) {  //if we included frames to show for breaking and the current frame is less than the max number of frames to play

        if (animateblink < 6) {


      [sprite setTexture:[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_blinkk00%i.png", baseImageName,animateblink]] texture]];

    [self unschedule:_cmd];
    [self schedule:@selector(openEyes:) interval:0.1f];

            [self schedule:@selector(moveSprite:) interval:0.1f];
}
    }
}
```

i have 6 images of animating like

```
dragonimage_blinkk001,dragonimage_blinkk002,dragonimage_blinkk003,dragonimage_blinkk004,dragonimage_blinkk005,dragonimage_blinkk006 like that
```

i put two methods,
1: for animation time
2: for movement of the image

the code is

```
-(void) openEyes:(ccTime) delta {

    [sprite setTexture:[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", baseImageName]] texture]];


    [self unschedule:_cmd];

    int blinkInterval = (arc4random() % 6) + 1; // range 3 to 8
    [self schedule:@selector(blink:) interval:blinkInterval];
}


-(void)moveSprite:(ccTime)delta

{
    movementCounter ++;
    if (movementCounter == 1000) {
        [self unschedule:_cmd];
    }
    else
    {
        spriteimagename.position = ccp(spriteimagename.position.x+10,spriteimagename.position.y);
    }
}
```

but on the first method the animation time is not correct,there is a lot of delay of animation,i just want to show animation of the images randomly and fast,its a dragon flying animation.

my sec on method is not at all working,i didn't get any movement of that image.

i hope you understand my issue.how to solve the above two method issues.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to have a read of http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:animation. Especially the CCAnimate section

Comment: @Ben i can't do this with the help of sprite sheet,,becz i need to pass this value thebaseimagename to some other class

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution is to add frameIndex member in cocos2d CCSpriteFrame class. i don't know is that allowed to change. But it works fine.

```
@interface CCSpriteFrame : NSObject <NSCopying>
{
        int          frameIndex;
        ....
}
```

//Here in code initialize frames with unique index

```
CCAnimation* animation;

    NSMutableArray *animFrames2 = [NSMutableArray array];
    for( int i=1;i<=15;i++)
    {
        CCSpriteFrame *frame = [cache spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ActerSmash_%d.png",i]];
        frame.frameIndex = (int)i;
        [animFrames2 addObject:frame];
    }
    animation = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:animFrames2];

    CCAnimate *action = [CCAnimate actionWithDuration:ACTER_SMASH_SPEED animation:animation restoreOriginalFrame:YES];
    action.tag = kTagAnimationSmashAnim ;
    mActer.AnimSmash = action;
```

//Checking frame Index

```
  CCAnimate *anim = mActer.AnimSmash ;

    for(CCSpriteFrame *frame in anim.animation.frames)
    {
      if([mActer isFrameDisplayed:frame] )  )
            {
                if(frame.frameIndex == 5 )
                {
                    //Do something..
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: this i not woking...i use want to make movmnt for my image

Comment: @stackiphone, Yes, me also used movement for my image, that worked for me. I think you are not referring same sprite animation frames, now edited my answer that may help.